# React conditional rendering not recognising true from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, return

So I have this simple function with conditional return:

```
export default function App() {
const appState = useState({
signed: true,
user: {
  login: null,
  password: null,
  rights: null,
},
});

return <div className="app">{appState.signed ? "does not" : "work"}</div>;
}
```

The problem is that the code always returns "work".
Is it not possible to use conditional rendering with state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useState hook returns an array of length 2.

```
 const [appState, changeAppState ] = useState({
signed: true,
user: {
  login: null,
  password: null,
  rights: null,
},
});

...

//To change signed to true, try using the callback pattern

    changeAppState ((prevAppState) => ({
       ...prevAppState,
      signed: false
    }));
    
//You can do this, but callback approach is safer

    changeAppState ({
       ...prevAppState,
       signed: false
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The `useState` hook gives you an array with the state value and a setter method.

The problem is that you're accessing that array returned by `useState` and  you can't access `signed` it results in a `false` which makes the text 'work' to be displayed

So do this instead

```js
export default function App() {

  const [appState, setAppState] = useState({
    signed: true,
    user: {
      login: null,
      password: null,
      rights: null,
    },
  });

 return <div className="app">{appState.signed ? "does not" : "work"}</div>;
}
```